# Adding a final double to my program

Tags: java, double, final

I'm attempting to make a few doubles in my code final.  I've tried a few methods such as "public static final," just "final," etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Pay_stub {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

        double fedinctax = .15;
        double statetax = .035;
        double socsectax = .0575;
        double meditax = .0275;
        double penplan = .05;
        double healthins = 75;

        double hoursworked;
        double hourlyrate;

        double netpay;
        double grosspay;

        String firstname, lastname;

        System.out.println("Enter employee first name: ");
        firstname = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter employee last name: ");
        lastname = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursworked = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter hourly rate: ");
        hourlyrate = input.nextDouble();

        grosspay = hoursworked * hourlyrate;

        double fit = grosspay * fedinctax;
        double st = grosspay * statetax;
        double sst = grosspay * socsectax;
        double mmt = grosspay * meditax;
        double pp = grosspay * penplan;
        double total = fit + st + sst + mmt + pp + healthins;
        double net = grosspay - total;

        System.out.println(firstname + lastname + "'s monthly paycheck is: ");
        System.out.println("Gross Pay: " + (df.format(grosspay)));
        System.out.println("Federal Income Tax: " + fit);
        System.out.println("State Tax: " + st);
        System.out.println("Social Security Tax: " + sst);
        System.out.println("Medicare/Medicaid Tax: " + mmt);
        System.out.println("Pension Plan: " + pp);
        System.out.println("Health Insurance: " + healthins);
        System.out.println("Net Pay: " + (df.format(net)));
    }
}
```

These are what I would like to make final:

```
    double fedinctax = .15;
    double statetax = .035;
    double socsectax = .0575;
    double meditax = .0275;
    double penplan = .05;
    double healthins = 75;
```

I just am not sure where I'm supposed to put the final lines in the code, or how they are supposed to be written

Comment: Just add the word "final" and a space at the beginning of each line. "Public" and "static" are not valid for variables like these that are declared inside a method.

Comment: If you're getting an error message, you should say what the error message is, and post a (short) program that actually demonstrates the error.

Comment: you can think of a 'final' variable as a constant, it can't change. Once you make something final its there with same value for the whole life of that scope (method/block/whole app depending of where you declare it). the example that you give all the double at the beginning (fedinctax etc.) can be final in that method. but since there actual constants you can declare as 'static final' in the current class and use them anywhere (in the class if private or outside if public by doing 'Pay_stub.fedinctax')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final double fedinctax = .15;
```

By the way, instead of using

```
final double fedinctax = .15;
final double statetax = .035;
final double socsectax = .0575;
...
```

You can just do

```
final double fedinctax = .15,
             statetax = .035,
             socsectax = .0575,
             ...
```

Or (indentation doesn't matter)

```
final double fedinctax = .15, statetax = .035, socsectax = .0575, ...
```

So you don't have to keep retyping "`final double`" over and over again. (Same thing goes for normal `double`s, or any other type for that matter)

Also, the naming convention for final fields is `ALL_CAPS`, for example: `final double STATE_TAX`

Comment: Thanks.  I was placing the "final" after the "double."  While this is what I wanted to do to make these finals, on my assignment sheet it used examples like: public static final double FEDERAL_INCOME_TAX=.15;  Would this be something different than just making my doubles final?

Comment: @Patrick That's just the naming convention for final variables

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a list of constants that are known at run time, the preferred thing to do is to create an enum.  You can associate the data with the enum lable in the enum.

This is preferred to the pattern of making your array of constants static and final.  Enums are type safe and instance controlled for you, whereas static final constants have only limited type safety.

Your constants are somewhat heterogenous (they appear to not all have the same base type), but here is an example of an enum called "Withholdings":

```
enum Withholding {
    FEDERAL_INCOME (0.15),
    STATE_INCOME (0.035),
    SOCIAL_SECURITY (0.0575),
    MEDICARE (0.0275),
    PERSONAL_RETIREMENT (0.05);

    private final double rate;

    Withholding (double r) {
        this.rate = r;
    }

    getRate() { return this.rate; }
}
```

To access the withholding rate on pre-tax income, for example, you would use the following in your code:

```
   double fed_withholding = gross_salary * Withholding.FEDERAL_INCOME.getRate();
```

There are many advantages to using enums over lists of constants.  When such a list is known to you at compile time, you'll find it much easier to maintain, more readible, and more robust to use enum declarations instead of a declared constant pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've yet to learn these but it looks like it will be some valuable information for the near future.